# How to compare two cumulative distributions if the number of observations per individual are different?

Tags: distributions, modeling, group-differences

## Problem Description

I have simulated the movement of cars in a lane. The simulation model was first calibrated based on an observed car traffic. Now, I have vectors of speeds (collected every 0.1 seconds per car) for observed and simulated traffic. Let's say I have 15 observed cars, each having different number of observations, e.g:

```
Car_ID Time Speed
Car 1 0.0 40.00
Car 1 0.1 40.02
Car 1 0.2 40.07
.
.
.
Car 15 0.0 42.00
Car 15 0.1 41.90
Car 15 0.2 41.80
Car 15 0.3 42.00
```

Similarly, I have another dataset containing the speeds of simulated vehicles. The total number of samples (rows) and samples per a `Car_ID` are different between observed and simulated data.

## Question

The speed at time t of a given `Car_ID` is correlated with its previous speeds. Is a comparison of cumulative speed distribution diagrams of observed and simulated data fair in this context?